# Openshift v2 migration to Openshift V3

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3

We had our platform hosted on Openshift v2 however due to budget and human resource constraints we were never able to migrate to Openshift v3. We now have the budget and resources in place, however, they are unable to locate our platform. It points to the rhcloud.com.

Any advice on if we can still locate our platform to migrate to v3.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you were keeping the application code you were pushing up to OpenShift V2 in a local repository and should be able to recover it from that. If you were doing everything in OpenShift V2 and not keeping backups of data or code in some form, then you have missed the cutoff. Notice was given in:

- https://blog.openshift.com/migrate-to-v3-v2-eol/

as well as via emails to account holders. For free Bronze tier the cut off was back in October. If you were a paying customer you would still have been able to retrieve code and data through to January. If you were a paying customer and want to be certain that nothing can still be retrieved, then use your support channel to ask.